# Por que essa query não funciona no Oracle?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, tradução

Estou traduzindo uma query do SQL Server para o Oracle e encontrei um erro que não faz sentido e eu não estou conseguindo corrigir.

O erro apresentado é o seguinte:

```
ORA-00904: "ITM"."NRO_INT_ITEM": identificador inválido
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Erro na linha: 20 Coluna: 42
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Query SQL Server (Que funciona)

```
SELECT    
FORMAT(ISNULL(DAQ.DTH_DEMANDA,'9999-01-01'), 'yyyy-MM') + '-01' DT_MOV                              
, ITM.NRO_INT_ITEM
, ( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT SQRY_DAQ.NRO_INT_TAREFA) QTD_DEMANDA       
    FROM  TAREFAS SQRY_DAQ
    INNER JOIN ITEM_DEMANDADO SQRY_ITD
        ON SQRY_DAQ.NRO_INT_TAREFA = SQRY_ITD.NRO_INT_TAREFA                                                
        AND SQRY_DAQ.NRO_INT_TAREFA = DAQ.NRO_INT_TAREFA
        AND SQRY_ITD.NRO_INT_ITEM = ITD.NRO_INT_ITEM
        AND SQRY_ITD.NRO_INT_ITEM = ITM.NRO_INT_ITEM) 
QTD_DEMANDA
, 0 QTD_REQUISICAO
, 0 QTD_COMPRA
FROM  ITEM ITM
LEFT JOIN ITEM_DEMANDADO ITD
ON ITD.NRO_INT_ITEM = ITM.NRO_INT_ITEM
LEFT JOIN TAREFAS DAQ
ON DAQ.NRO_INT_TAREFA = ITD.NRO_INT_TAREFA
```

Query Oracle (Que está com problema)

```
SELECT    
TO_DATE(NVL(DAQ.DTH_SOME_DATA,'9999-01-01'), 'YYYY-MM') + '-01' DT_MOV                              
, ITM.NRO_INT_ITEM
, ( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT SQRY_DAQ.NRO_INT_TAREFA) QTD_DEMANDA       
FROM   TAREFAS SQRY_DAQ
INNER  JOIN ITEM_DEMANDADO SQRY_ITD
       ON SQRY_DAQ.NRO_INT_TAREFA = SQRY_ITD.NRO_INT_TAREFA                                             
       AND SQRY_DAQ.NRO_INT_TAREFA = DAQ.NRO_INT_TAREFA
       AND SQRY_ITD.NRO_INT_ITEM = ITD.NRO_INT_ITEM
       AND SQRY_ITD.NRO_INT_ITEM = ITM.NRO_INT_ITEM) 
QTD_UM
, 0 QTD_DOIS
, 0 QTD_TRES
FROM  ITEM ITM
LEFT JOIN ITEM_DEMANDADO ITD
    ON ITD.NRO_INT_ITEM = ITM.NRO_INT_ITEM
LEFT JOIN TAREFAS DAQ
    ON DAQ.NRO_INT_TAREFA = ITD.NRO_INT_TAREFA
```

Comment: O **alias** é entre aspas não é ? `LEFT JOIN ITEM_DEMANDADO "ITD"`

Comment: A tabela  ITEM Item a coluna .NRO_INT_ITEM ?

Comment: @Zooboomafoo Depende, se o nome não conter espaços tu não precisa usar aspas, logo pode ser ISSO_EH_UM_ALIAS, mas nunca vai poder ser ISSO EH UM ALIAS, então precisa colocar entre aspas para ser possivel usar 'ISSO EH UM ALIAS'

Comment: @Motta Sim, ele tem essa coluna :/

Comment: Não falta uma vírgula antes de `QTD_UM`?

Comment: Tem como você disponibilizar o script de criação das tabelas? Só com as colunas necessárias, claro. Aí a gente consegue testar, caso contrário fica ruim.

Comment: Se você tira o alias funciona a consulta ?

Comment: @Zooboomafoo No oracle não

Comment: @jbueno n man, ali é o nome do select http://prntscr.com/duoqv0

Comment: É vero. Não tô acostumado a não usar o `AS`.

Comment: @AndreyHartung Não sei se é o caso e nem se haveria a possibilidade de você usar, mas o Oracle Golden Gate permite você migrar o banco inteiro em tempo real e sem a necessidade de para-lo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema está na sua subquery (QTD_UM).

A tabela de alias `ITM` não pode ser utilizado na condição de join naquele ponto.

Para correção, bastaria colocar as condições de join que utilizam as colunas da query principal na cláusula `where`:

```
      SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT SQRY_DAQ.NRO_INT_TAREFA) QTD_DEMANDA
      FROM   TAREFAS SQRY_DAQ
      INNER JOIN ITEM_DEMANDADO SQRY_ITD  ON SQRY_DAQ.NRO_INT_TAREFA = SQRY_ITD.NRO_INT_TAREFA
      ---------------------------------------------------
      where SQRY_DAQ.NRO_INT_TAREFA = DAQ.NRO_INT_TAREFA
      and   SQRY_ITD.NRO_INT_ITEM = ITD.NRO_INT_ITEM
      and   SQRY_ITD.NRO_INT_ITEM = ITM.NRO_INT_ITEM
      ---------------------------------------------------
```

Outro problema está na máscara de datas utilizada.

Não sei como está populada a coluna `TAREFAS.DTH_SOME_DATA`, mas é necessário que o formato utilizado pelo conteúdo desta coluna e o valor utilizado no comando `nvl` estejam exatamente com o formato especificado no comando `to_date`.

No caso, a consulta utiliza um `nvl` no formato `yyyy-mm-dd`, mas realiza o `to_date` no formato `yyyy-mm`.

Comment: Perfeito! Funcionou parceiro obrigado! Eu só não entendi o pq isso não funciona no Oracle.. Teria alguma explicação?

Comment: O motivo real não saberia dizer.. mas existem algumas limitações de escopo no Oracle ao referenciar um campo de uma query em uma subquery na clausula select. Uma subquery com mais de um nível, como por exemplo select ( select 1 from ( select 1 from dual where a.dummy /* ORA-00904: "A"."DUMMY": invalid identifier */ = 'X' ) ) from dual a apresentaria o mesmo erro. Provavelmente internamente as condições de join são convertidas para uma query semelhante.